# What type of sensor connection would be the most suitable?

Tags: connector, wiring, pinout, transducer, pressure

I have a pressure transducer with a 6 pin bayonet MIL-C-26482 male connector. I need to wire this connector with a 9 pin female D sub analog input connector and I am not sure how to do so.

Schematic of the 9 pin connector: 
[image]

The 6 pin bayonet male connector has the following schematic: 
For pins A to F-

```
        A: +ve supply
        B: +ve output
        C: -ve output
        D: -ve supply
        E&F: Shunt calibration
```

This is the manual for the DAQ system which contains the D- Sub connector as an analog input pin: https://d36j349d8rqm96.cloudfront.net/3/6/DEWE-43_user%20manual.pdf

This is the link to the pressure transducer with 6 pin bayonet male connector: http://www.southeastern-automation.com/PDF/GESensing/Pressure/5000%20Series.pdf
Here's the link to the pressure sensor with the 6 pin bayonet connector:http://www.southeastern-automation.com/PDF/GESensing/Pressure/5000%20Series.pdf

I'm thinking that the 6 wire full-bridge sensor connection would be the most suitable, but I am not sure.

Types of sensor connections available:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Chapter 4 covers the connections for a wide range of sensor types. Are you having trouble identifying what kind of sensor you have?

Comment: Yeah, I think that's my main issue. I don't understand which sensor connection is the most suitable.